# De Bruijn–Erdős theorem for hypergraphs

Tags: set-theory, graph-colorings, infinite-combinatorics, hypergraph

The [De Bruijn–Erdős theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn%E2%80%93Erd%C5%91s_theorem_(graph_theory))  states that  when all finite subgraphs of a graph $G$ can be colored with $n$ colors, the same is true for the whole graph.

There is a natural notion of coloring for [hypergraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) which is as follows. Let $H= (V, E)$ be a hypergraph, and let $\kappa\neq \emptyset$ be a cardinal. Then a map $c:V\to\kappa$ is said to be a *(hypergraph) coloring* if the restriction $c\restriction_e : e \to \kappa$ is non-constant whenever $e$ has more than $1$ element.

Is the following statement true?

> Let $n>1$ be an integer, and let $H=(V,E)$ be a hypergraph such that for all finite $E_0\subseteq E$, the hypergraph $(V,E_0)$ can be colored with $n$ colors. Then $H$ can be colored with $n$ colors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The space $X=\{1,\dots,n\}^V$ of all colorings (proper or not) of $H=(V,E)$ with $n$ colors is compact in the product topology. Given a finite set $F \subset E$, the set $K_{F}$ of proper colorings of $(V,F)$ is a closed  set in $X$.

For any finite collection
$F_1,\dots,F_k$ of finite subsets of $E$, the intersection
$$\cap_{j=1}^k K_{F_j}=K_{\cup_{j=1}^k F_j}$$ is nonempty by the given hypothesis.
Therefore, by compactness of $X$, the intersection
$$\bigcap  \{K_F : \, F \; \text{finite}, \; \,  F \subset E \}  $$
is nonempty, and any coloring in this intersection is a proper coloring of $H=(V,E)$.

Comment: Very cool - I would never have thought of applying compactness and Tikhonov here!